# How i can create context menu for extjs panel

Tags: extjs4

i have context menu like

```
var ctxMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    items: [{ text: 'Edit', action: 'edit'}]
});
```

how i can add this to extjs panel? I am not seeing any suitable event in panel, like `itemcontextmenu` in treepanel?

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `itemcontextmenu` and `containercontextmenu` events in `Ext.tree.Panel`.

Update: same events exist for Ext.grid.Panel. You probably want to subscribe for both of them and do something like that:

```
showContextMenu: function(e) {
    var me = this;

    if (me.contextMenu === undefined)
        return;

    e.stopEvent();
    me.contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
},

// Show context menu from the grid
gridContextMenu: function(view, rec, node, index, e) {
    this.showContextMenu(e);
},

// Show context menu from the empty area below grid records
containerContextMenu: function(view, e) {
    this.showContextMenu(e);
},
```

Comment: actually i need to add context menu in Ext.panel.Panel (xtype: panel)

Comment: Same thing. It's all there. You just need to present it properly. Look for Menu documentation

Comment: I didn't get..I also need to add menu on right click in xtype:'panel'..can anyone help by posting code?

Comment: do you add these functions as listeners? do you add them directly to the component?

Comment: @OliverWatkins: you add `gridContentMenu` and `containerContextMenu` as listeners to events

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Sencha ExtJS 7.4 on a Ext.panel.Panel:

```
listeners: {
    el: {
        contextmenu: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
                items: [{
                    text: 'Cut',
                    iconCls: 'cut',
                    handler: 'onCut'
                },{
                    text: 'Delete',
                    iconCls: 'delete',
                    handler: 'onDelete'
                }]
            });
            contextMenu.showBy(Ext.getCmp(blockId+'-panel'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).